# How do I convert 1M OHLC to 5M OHLC using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, resampling

I am trying to convert 1M OHLC to 5M OHLC for a bunch of files using pandas

This is how my data looks like:

```
dateTime             | open   | high | low | close | vol |
-----------------------------------------------------------
01-06-2018  00:50:00 | 0.97456| 0.2456|0.2145|0.241|54.26
01-06-2018  00:51:00 | 0.94566| 0.2145|0.1455|0.214|65.24
01-06-2018  00:52:00 | 0.89654| 0.2145|0.2144|0.214|73.25
```

How do I resample and save as a 5M OHLC csv

Thanks in advance

edit 1: This is what i get with print (df.info())

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 375660 entries, 2018-06-01 00:00:00 to 2019-05-31 20:59:00
Data columns (total 4 columns):
open     375660 non-null float64
high     375660 non-null float64
low      375660 non-null float64
close    375660 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 14.3+ MB
None
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) with dictionary for columns names with aggregation with `5T` for `5 minutes`:

```
d = {'open':'first', 'high':'max','low':'min','close':'last','vol':'sum'}

df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'])
df = df.resample('5T', on='dateTime').agg(d)
print (df)
                        open    high     low  close     vol
dateTime                                                   
2018-01-06 00:50:00  0.97456  0.2456  0.1455  0.214  192.75
```

Comment: Hey I am getting the output in a lots of columns(4 x 48) that is in a completely different format; nothing similar to your output.

Comment: @SrikanthVarma - What is `print (df.info())` of your input dataframe?

Comment: @SrikanthVarma - So after my solution you get 40 columns? It is weird, because for me working nice. Can you add some 3-4 rows from your output?

Comment: My entire output consists of only 6 rows

Comment: @SrikanthVarma - My first solution was wrong, do you use `5T` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using 5T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197688/discussion-between-srikanth-varma-and-jezrael).